# Handlebars does not support empty template

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have some problems with `handlebars`. I have a template:

`<input id="some-id" size="40" value={{someValue}} placeholder="bla bla"/>`

When `someValue` is empty line, my template crashes (see attached image).[image]

Version of handlebars is 4.0.8

Comment: make zoom in navigator, or is as shown?

Comment: Did not make zoom.

Comment: bufff, pixels are little big?

Comment: hmm, how does this relate to my problem?

Comment: I blurred some part of navigator and left only significant part

Comment: mmm, then i dont got a idea of what is happens

Comment: I'm expecting such input: `<input id="some-id" size="40" value='' placeholder="bla bla"/>` but getting crashed input

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping `{{someValue}}` in quotes helped me: 
`<input id="some-id" size="40" value="{{someValue}}" placeholder="bla bla"/>`